# Networkx - python - No shorter path found even if it exist

Tags: python, networkx, geopandas, shortest-path, osmnx

I'm currently working with Networkx in order to find the shortest path in an OSM network.
My problem is that when executing my script, I have always this error except for nodes that are side by side :

"networkx.exception.NetworkXNoPath: No path between 208769027 and 208769047.
No path found"

The problem is that I'm pretty sure that there is a path between these two nodes. (I used the same graph file with qgis and executed the qgis algorithm to find the shortest path and it's working with the same nodes).

Here is my script (I have to save the files to gpkg format for my project)

```
import os
os.environ['USE_PYGEOS'] = '0'
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import fiona
import shapely.geometry as geom
import geopandas as gpd
import traceback
from data_utils import create_folder


def load_osm_network(network_paramaters):
    print("Loading OSM network")

    # Retrieve the street network graph
    if(network_paramaters["bbox"] !=None):
        north, south, east, west = network_paramaters["bbox"]
        G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type=network_paramaters["network_type"], simplify=True)
    else:
        G = ox.graph_from_place(network_paramaters["place_name"], network_type=network_paramaters["network_type"], simplify=False)

    G = ox.project_graph(G, to_crs="EPSG:4171")

    print("OSM network loaded, saving into file..")
    # Save the graph data as a GeoPackage file
    create_folder("./data/osm")
    ox.save_graph_geopackage(G, filepath=network_paramaters["output_file"])

lyon_network_parameters = {
    "place_name" : "Lyon, France",
    "network_type" : "drive",
    "bbox": None,
    "output_file": "./data/osm/lyon_drive.gpkg"
}


bbox_network_parameters = {
    "place_name": "Lyon, France",
    "network_type": "walk",
    "bbox": (45.76091,45.74938, 4.89007,4.86426),
    "output_file" : "./data/osm/bbox_default_crs.gpkg"
}

load_osm_network(lyon_network_parameters)
load_osm_network(bbox_network_parameters)


def shortest_path(graph_file_path, shortest_path_file_path, origin_point, destination_point):
    # Load the graph data from the GeoPackage file

    gdf_edges = gpd.read_file(graph_file_path, layer='edges')
    gdf_nodes = gpd.read_file(graph_file_path, layer="nodes")

    gdf_edges = gdf_edges.set_index(['u', 'v', 'key'])
    gdf_nodes = gdf_nodes.set_index(['osmid'])

    G = ox.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)

    origin_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=origin_point[1], Y=origin_point[0])
    destination_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G, X=destination_point[1], Y=destination_point[0])

    print(origin_node)
    print(destination_node)

    print("type G : ", type(G))

    try:
        # Calculate the shortest path astar's algorithm
        #shortest_path = nx.astar_path(G, origin_node, destination_node, heuristic=manhattan_distance, weight="length")
        # Calculate the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm
        shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, source=origin_node, target=destination_node, weight="length")


        print(type(shortest_path))
        print(shortest_path)

        # Convert the shortest path to a LineString geometry
        route_edges = ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G, shortest_path)
        
        gdf_route_edges = gpd.GeoDataFrame(route_edges, crs=G.graph['crs'], geometry='geometry')

        gdf_route_edges.to_file(shortest_path_file_path, driver='GPKG')

        print("Shortest path found")

    except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("No path found")

#create_folder("./data/osm/shortest_path/")

origin_point = (45.7587161, 4.8737715)
destination_point = (45.7596251,4.8743205)

shortest_path("./data/osm/bbox_default_crs.gpkg", "./data/osm/shortest_path/_bbox_first_trial.gpkg", origin_point=origin_point, destination_point=destination_point)
```

I tried with several kind of algorithm of networkx but no one worked.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Is qgis using a directed graph or an undirected graph. There is probably no path between these nodes in the directed graph, but there is in an undirected representation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @gboeing, I don't know if it is linked with undirected and directed graph but I found a solution for my problem, the problem was the type of graph used by the function shortest_path, I convert my MultiDiGraph into Graph and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem converting MultiDiGraph into Graph :

Here is the corrected code :

```
def shortest_path(graph_file_path, shortest_path_file_path, origin_point, destination_point):
   # Load the graph data from the GeoPackage file

   gdf_edges = gpd.read_file(graph_file_path, layer='edges')
   gdf_nodes = gpd.read_file(graph_file_path, layer="nodes")

   gdf_edges = gdf_edges.set_index(['u', 'v', 'key'])
   gdf_nodes = gdf_nodes.set_index(['osmid'])

   G = ox.graph_from_gdfs(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)

   G2 = nx.Graph(G)

   origin_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G2, X=origin_point[1], Y=origin_point[0])
   destination_node = ox.nearest_nodes(G2, X=destination_point[1], Y=destination_point[0])

   try:
       # Calculate the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm
       shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G2, source=origin_node, target=destination_node, weight="length")

       G3 = nx.MultiDiGraph(G2)

       route_edges = ox.utils_graph.get_route_edge_attributes(G3, shortest_path)

       gdf_route_edges = gpd.GeoDataFrame(route_edges, crs=G.graph['crs'], geometry='geometry')

       gdf_route_edges.to_file(shortest_path_file_path, driver='GPKG')

       print("Shortest path found")

   except nx.NetworkXNoPath:
       traceback.print_exc()
       print("No path found")
```